# Как получить значение EditText из AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как получить текст, введенный в поле `EditText`?

Пробую получать, но приложение падает.

```
public void onCreateDialogsValue() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Введите ключ")
            .setView((LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.regs_email, null))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Проверить ключ",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            EditText value_key = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value_key);
                            toster(String.valueOf(value_key.getText()));
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            );
    builder.show();
}
```

Скриншот загрузить не могу, но, думаю, всё понятно из кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно искать ваш `EditText` в самом диалоге, то есть в той `View`, которую вы отинфлейтили, а не где то в ваккуме. Это не активити, здесь нужно явно задавать, где осуществлять поиск виджета:

```
public void onCreateDialogsValue() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.regs_email, null);
        final EditText valueKey = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.value_key);
        builder.setTitle("Введите ключ")
                .setView(view)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Проверить ключ",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                toster(String.valueOf(valueKey.getText()));
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

PS: рекомендуется придерживаться правил именования переменных и полей в Java : не `value_key`, а `valueKey`

Comment: Спасибо, не додумал:) Все работает!