# Проблемы с поиском EditText по id в AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext

Доброго времени суток!
При написании программы с диалоговым окном, столкнулся с проблемой.
В "Позитивной кнопочке" пытаюсь инициализировать EditText по айди, но почему-то при дебаге в переменной null. Код ниже:

```
package ru.vladimir.cats;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nameEdit;
    EditText textEdit;
    EditText deadlineEdit;
    EditText importanceEdit;

    String name;
    String text;
    String deadline;
    int importance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addTask(View v){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Добавить задачу");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            nameEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            textEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
            deadlineEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.deadline);
            importanceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.importance);

            Editable a = nameEdit.getText();
            name = a.toString();
            a = textEdit.getText();
            text = a.toString();
            a = deadlineEdit.getText();
            deadline = a.toString();
            a = importanceEdit.getText();
            importance = Integer.parseInt(a.toString());
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setView(R.layout.form);


    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433864/177345

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас в AlertDialog'e есть EditText - вам надо искать его именно в диалоге, а не в активити.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(getActivity());
EditText etName = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

И уже потом брать информацию. pavlofff правильно сказал, Вы пытаетесь найти EditText в активити, в котором его нет, отсюда и null.

Answer (score 0):

я порекомендовал бы вам использовать Binding для упрощения кода и поиска по элемента. К тому же это очень удобно.